# Are there any Wifi/Networked Lights available to purchase?

Tags: light, wifi, network-interface

## Summary

I'm trying to find a light that can be connected straight into a network via WIFI or LAN Cable (cat5, etc..).

## Details

We have a server which handles automated builds and deployment for our website development. If the automated build (aka our continuous integration) failed, we would like to be told.

So - traditionally, people have been using lights or monitors to visually display the status of their builds.

green - last build worked 100% fine.
yellow - in progress
red - last build failed.

So, I was hoping to find a light (bulb/lava lamp/whatever) that can be connected to the network and I can hack up a program to then tell that light to display as red/yellow/green, depending on the state of the build.

So - are there any lights that can be connected to a network, preferably via WIFI but via cable is fine. I'm assuming they will also need a power plug to get power .. unless maybe the lan cable can supply power, if the light doesn't require too much?

Comment: Just to be clear: Are you looking to make a light or to buy a prefabricated device? If it's the second, than take a look at our [FAQ](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: I would prefer #2 .. BUT .. it's assumed I would have to do some hacking/coding with it (which i'm totally kewl with). Otherwise, i'm kewl to get some parts and make something up - if there is enough guidance :)

Comment: I don't have a lot of guidance to offer, but a starting point would be to get soemthing like [this](http://www.mikroe.com/eng/products/view/596/serial-ethernet-2-board/) or [this](http://www.mikroe.com/eng/products/view/572/easywifi-board/) and connect it to a microcontroller board like [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/en/). Then just connect LEDs you like to the microcontroller board and the only remaining part would be programming.(Note that I posted links only to illustrate what you should be looking for, I have no experience with those products, so I can't say if they're good, bad or ugly)

Comment: Personally, I would just have the automated build process send an email when it's done.  When this email is sent to specific addresses, like _cell_phone_number_@attwireless.net then the email would be sent as a text message to your phone.  Nothing to build, and doesn't need line-of-sight to work.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you're ready to write code to make such a device.  Even if there was something as simple as a networkable LED, you'd have to write custom code to parse the build output file so you could choose a color to display.  And since you want this for a build server, I'm already assuming that you can write code.  :)

The first product that came to mind was a thing I remember from a couple of years ago -- it looked like a rabbit and the ears would go up or down, and change color.  I think it was supposed to report the general mood of the internet, at least for things that interest you, like stocks and sports.  Stocks up == good == green == ears up.  Favorite team loses == bad == red == ears down.

But I couldn't find that product anymore, so the next most logical, hackable, open "network LED" is the Chumby / Chumby One.  You can [read about it here](http://www.chumby.com/pages/chumby_one).

That said, why don't you use the free network LED, which is basically a monitor hooked up to a cheap PC that meta refreshes the results page from your integration server?

EDIT -- so my joke about a "free network LED" wasn't well received.  :)  If you want to keep development of this to a minimum, then two good options are Arduino / Netduino and mbed.  Arduino + ethernet shield make it super simple to get your embedded device on the network and is outlined [here](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClient).  mbed is another candidate and looks pretty easy to get hooked up to your network.  There are examples like [this](http://mbed.org/users/no2chem/notebook/ethernet-testing/) and [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQm2B6BqU1I) for getting the networking going.

Comment: You're thinking of the Nabaztag (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabaztag); they don't work terribly well in my experience (just won't connect to modern wifi networks).

Comment: *free network LED* ??? What's that? If it is *literally* hooking up a monitor to a PC or a USB Light .. then nope. I was hoping to have an individual solution not dependent upon another computer (which also has to be ON).

Comment: @Pure.Krome I was just speaking metaphorically, so yes I was being literal.  Sounds like you need Chumby, or better, a simple embedded ethernet solution.  You're at the right place for the latter option -- you can pick numerous embedded microcontrollers for this task.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Robert Atkins: thanks!!!  For the life of me, I just couldn't remember the name of that product.  If it didn't work so well, I guess I understand why I couldn't find it last night.  :)  I was searching for stuff "network rabbit bunny".  haha

Comment: I'm going to do this with a Netduino plus or equivalent (not least because I'm very comfortable with .NET)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the [Ambient Orb](http://www.ambientdevices.com/cat/orb/orborder.html).

Unfortunately, I think they're not being manufactured any more. Might find one on Ebay.

Answer (score 1):

I've searched long and hard for this before and the best I've come up with are networked power switches from [this manufacturer](http://www.leunig.de/_en/_pro/remote_power_switches.html). They have an embedded web server, so you could easily hack together a plugin for your CI server to switch lava lamps on and off after a build.

Note they're Ethernet only and **very** expensive as from what I can tell these type of products are intended for data centre operations.

(Upon further googling, I also find [this](http://www.digital-loggers.com/lpc.html), which is wifi and cheaper, but apparently on backorder. They say they have similar products available now though.)